How can I pre-fault and lock memory pages that are mmap'd with MAP_PRIVATE?
I am writing a real-time linux application where I need to prevent any page faults from occuring after the initial startup of my application.
My initial thought was just to call mlockall(MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE);. Calling this function returns no error code, but if I inspect my process's pages, it looks like there are still many pages that have the Locked: size at 0 (which I assume means those pages can still cause a page-fault).
$ cat /proc/<pid>/smaps |  grep -B 21 -A 2 "Locked:                0 kB"  | grep -B 1 "^Size:" | grep -v "Size" | grep -v "^\-\-"
7effd0021000-7effd4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effd4021000-7effd8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effd80c6000-7effdc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effddf02000-7effddfa0000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7effddfa0000-7effde1a0000 rw-s f0000000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7effde1c1000-7effde1c2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effde1c6000-7effde1ca000 rw-s f7c00000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7effde1ca000-7effde1cb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effe221b000-7effe221c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effe2220000-7effe2223000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 90                         /dev/another_char_device
7effe22df000-7effe22e0000 ---p 00013000 08:02 2234654                    /<path_to>/shared_library1.so
7effe22fd000-7effe22fe000 ---p 0000c000 08:02 2231701                    /<path_to>/shared_library2.so
7effe23fc000-7effe23fd000 ---p 0001c000 08:02 2234652                    /<path_to>/shared_library3.so
7effe2e15000-7effe2e16000 ---p 00215000 08:02 1957                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7effe2e40000-7effe2e41000 ---p 00011000 08:02 2234649                    /<path_to>/shared_library4.so
7effe2f14000-7effe2f15000 ---p 00046000 08:02 2232115                    /<path_to>/shared_library5.so
7effe321a000-7effe321b000 ---p 0021a000 08:02 855                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30
7effe3258000-7effe3259000 ---p 0001f000 08:02 2234643                    /<path_to>/shared_library6.so
7effe327d000-7effe327e000 ---p 00021000 08:02 2234641                    /<path_to>/shared_library7.so
7effe328a000-7effe328b000 ---p 00009000 08:02 2232116                    /<path_to>/shared_library8.so
7effe348e000-7effe348f000 ---p 00102000 08:02 91759                      /<path_to>/shared_library9.so
7effe34c6000-7effe34c8000 r--p 00000000 08:02 175                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7effe34f2000-7effe34fd000 r--p 0002c000 08:02 175                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7ffc1d1b0000-7ffc1d1b4000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc1d1b4000-7ffc1d1b6000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Some attempts and some questions...
Attempt: Move the location of mlockall in the initialization function
My main function has a bunch of dlopen calls. Previously the mlockall call was after the calls to dlopen. Moving the call to mlockall before the dlopen calls seems to lock in the memory of the shared libraries that are loaded after it. However, it does not lock in the memory of shared libraries loaded before the call to mlockall (those shared libraries are linked at compile-time and specified in the executable).
Why doesn't MCL_CURRENT lock in already-loaded libraries?
$ cat /proc/<mypid>/smaps |  grep -B 21 -A 2 "Locked:                0 kB"  | grep -B 1 "^Size:" | grep -v "Size" | grep -v "^\-\-"
7fef0c021000-7fef10000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef10021000-7fef14000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef140c6000-7fef18000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef1875d000-7fef187fb000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7fef187fb000-7fef189fb000 rw-s f0000000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7fef18a0a000-7fef18a0b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef1ca2e000-7fef1ca2f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef1ca33000-7fef1ca37000 rw-s f7c00000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7fef1ca37000-7fef1ca38000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef1ca3c000-7fef1ca3f000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 90                         /dev/another_char_device
7fef1d615000-7fef1d616000 ---p 00215000 08:02 1957                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7fef1da1a000-7fef1da1b000 ---p 0021a000 08:02 855                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30
7fef1dcea000-7fef1dceb000 ---p 00102000 08:02 91760                      /<path_to>/shared_library9.so
7fef1dd22000-7fef1dd24000 r--p 00000000 08:02 175                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7fef1dd4e000-7fef1dd59000 r--p 0002c000 08:02 175                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7ffece1c4000-7ffece1c8000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffece1c8000-7ffece1ca000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Attempt: Use madvise to prefault pages
I tried calling this prefault function (inspired from here), but madvise seems to return a -1 or EPERM code on the pages with permissions ---p. If I understand correctly, those pages are mapped with MAP_PRIVATE and are supposed to be allocated in physical memory only when written to (as per the Copy-On-Write pattern). However, madvise does not seem to trigger the allocation, and just returns an error instead.
How can I pre-fault pages mapped with MAP_PRIVATE?

void prefault()
{
    const pid_t pid = getpid();
    
    FILE *fp;
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    char buf[4096];

    (void)snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%" PRIdMAX "/maps", (intmax_t)pid);

    fp = fopen(path, "r");

    volatile uint8_t val;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) {
        void *start, *end, *offset;
        int major, minor, n, ret;
        uint64_t inode;
        char prot[5];

        n = sscanf(buf, "%p-%p %4s %p %x:%x %" PRIu64 " %s\n",
            &start, &end, prot, &offset, &major, &minor,
            &inode, path);

   
        if (n < 7)        { continue; /* bad sscanf data        */ }
        if (start >= end) { continue; /* invalid addresse range */ }

        ret = madvise(start, (size_t)((uint8_t *)end - (uint8_t *)start), MADV_POPULATE_WRITE);
    }

    (void)fclose(fp);
}


For reference, this has also been asked on Stack Exchange in How can I pre-fault and lock memory pages that are mmap'd with MAP_PRIVATE?

Which Kernel version are you using? I have used mlockall on real time applications, but hadn't previously thought to check if shared libraries were locked or not.

Yes, I just posted the question in a couple forums to increase visibility! I am using kernel version 6.1.61

What is the RTOS?

I am using Xenomai 4 @agone
